# disable generation of generatedSample attribute in Response Representations of api configuration

Tags: azure-api-management

Is there a mechanism within Azure API Management to disable the generation of the sample data that is injected into the api specification by the APIM processes?

I have noticed in APIs that have significant large/complex models and a large number of operations that the sampleGenerated attribute is creating an extremely large overhead to the configuration of the api.  For example we have an api that is ~260k on original import of the swagger file and when it ends up in the APIM repository the configuration file has expanded out to over 13 megs of data.  This sample data doesn't appear to be used in the admin or developer portal so not sure of its value stored in the primary configuration file.  I have attempted to update via the repository to clear these values however it appears to be recreated after the repository update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do so is to provide your own samples.

Comment: Thanks I confirmed this with Microsoft as the only direct mechanism to manage the sample data content.  I did find out from MS that there is a setting with the APIM that can be requested through a support request to limit the size of the generated sample also.